# Visual Studio Code [Content] Command 'SFDX: Authorize an Org' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.auth.web.login' not found) [OK]

Tags: vs-code

my vs code was working fine including Authorise an Org. However, after I deleted authorised org details file in the .sfdx folder and deleted an alias in alias.json file. I started getting this error message. Please suggest the solution. thanks vab

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, it sounds like you accidently removed some important files that are required for Salesforce CLI.

I would retry installing Salesforce CLI to see if that fixes it.